# Forward declaration and include

Tags: c++, include, forward-declaration

I was using forward declaration and includes in one small project.

But sometimes if i created a file.

A that includes C and D.

And then include in B the A, C, D i had some problems, i added the forward declaration to it.

I noticed, that sometimes i just need the forward declaration, it happens because when i previous added it to a file that i includes in the file where the forward declaration is?
Like if i just include in B the A, so the C and D is included too?
I have an class where i just needed to add the forward declaration.
Like:

```
Class a;
Class b;
Class R{
}
```

then the file a included the R, so i didn't need to include the a in R, if i did that the code didn't compile. It says something like to declare a class before the {.

Other case is:

A forward declare B, but dont include B and B include A.. it works, i imagine that its because the time the compiler "paste" the A code in B, the forward declaration tells the compiler that the class is there down in the code. If i use ifdef/ifndef and include code b in a it crashes, if i remove the include it works as a charm ^^

Thanks.

Comment: What is your question? Generally, there are situations where a foward declaration is sufficient. But I can't see what your question is.

Comment: stackoverflow is a Q&A site. Have a look at a FAQ what is considered a good question and how to ask one. The problems you see (not having header guards, adding them leads to crashes) would point to some larger issue with your code.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you are introducing circular dependencies, which can be broken with forward declarations, just use an `#ifndef / #endif` pair:

```
#ifndef _FILE_H_
#define _FILE_H_

/* ... header file specifications ... */

#endif /* _FILE_H_ */
```

Comment: Its something like A forward declare B, but dont include B and B include A.. it works, i imagine that its because the time the  compiler "paste" the A code in B, the forward declaration tells the compiler that the class is there down in the code. If i use ifdef/ifndef and include code b in a it crashes, if i remove the include it works as a charm ^^.

Comment: I see. That's brought some clarity to the issue.

Comment: So its that what happen? XD, just to confirm

Answer (score -1):

I am too tired to think about all the dependencies you have there, but remember that #include is nothing more than insertion of included file exactly into the place of #include. This is done recursively until all #include directives are expanded.

It is also good to guard against multiple insertions of the same file by typical

```
#ifndef FILE_H
#define FILE_H
...
#endif
```

Comment: Maybe you should not answer if you are too tired to think about the question or if the question is in no state to be answered?